# Problem with Sequelize and specifying foreign key in an association

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have placements that belong to an App. The foreign_key on the placements table is appId (not AppId). I have specified as follows but get the error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column Placements.AppId does not exist
```

My Placement Model:

```
'use strict';
const App = require('./').App

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Placement = sequelize.define('Placement', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,

    isActive: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
  }, {
    tableName: 'placements'
  });
  Placement.associate = function(models) {
    Placement.belongsTo(models.App, { foreignKey: 'appId'})

    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return Placement;
};
```

How do I tell Sequelize that the foreignKey is appId and not AppId?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I don't see nothing wrong with your code. Which version of Sequelize are you using?

Just a couple of non-related comments:

1. You don't need to import App, it is already in models object.
2. I think you don't need tableName parameter either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the field property

```
Placement.belongsTo(models.App, { 
    foreignKey: {
        name: 'AppId',
        field: 'appId'
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the AppId columns present in App model. Explicitly passing `{ foreignKey: 'appId'})` to belongsTo makes Sequelize use the key as it is.

So you need to create an App model which has -

```
const App = sequelize.define('App', {
AppId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
..

}, {
tableName: 'App'
});
```

Another options would be to change this

`Placement.belongsTo(models.App, { foreignKey: 'appId'})`

to

`Placement.belongsTo(models.App)`

This way Sequelize automatically handles all relations between the models.